# Android viewpager pagertitlestrip click by position

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I'm working viewpager and pagertitlestrip.i successfully created it and i wan add  views in my viewpager.this is a my source

```
 private ViewPager mViewPager;
 TextView text;
 private PagerTitleStrip mPagerTitleStrip;
 View view1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mPagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip)findViewById(R.id.pagertitle);

    //View
    LayoutInflater mLi = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    view1 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    text=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //Title




    final ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();


    final ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         view1 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
         text=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

         text.setText("Page"+i);
         views.add(view1);
          titles.add("title"+i);


    }
    mPagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    //ViewPager
    PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter() {

           @Override
           public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                return arg0 == arg1;
           }

           @Override
           public int getCount() {
                return views.size();
           }

           @Override
           public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
                ((ViewPager)container).removeView(views.get(position));
           }

           @Override
           public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return titles.get(position);
           }

           @Override
           public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
                ((ViewPager)container).addView(views.get(position));
                return views.get(position);
           }
      };

      mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}
```

}

now i try to write  pagertitlestrip's onclicklistener.for more information,if i click 4's title i would to start(show) 4th view.onclick listener by position
how i can solve my problem?
if anyone knows solution please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set view manually by tapping on some indicator the you can use this

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(num);
```

but if you want to do something when some page is selected the you can use

```
ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener
```

for the listener understanding you can follow this

[ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

Hope this will help

Comment: it is a possible to click pagertitlestrip's second title(for example)and second view would show?

Comment: click pagertitlestrip's second title and in onClick listener set
    ViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);